# Swap and reverse elements in a python list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, slice

I have a list with elements as following:

```
L =[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I want to mirror and reorder as follows:

```
L =[1,5,2,4,3]
```

Numbers and size of elements in the list may vary and change!

Having some other examples,

```
K=[1, 2, 3]
```

Output may come out as:

```
K=[1, 3, 2]
```

And

```
D=[1,2,3,4]
```

Final results:

```
D = [1,4,2,3]
```

I have tried to do it with slice, it doesn't work for me.

Comment: What is your algorithm for swapping and mirroring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by merging the list with its reverse:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5]

b = [c for a,b in zip(lst,reversed(lst)) for c in (a,b)][:len(lst)]

print(b) # [1, 5, 2, 4, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
from random import shuffle

my_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
print (my_list)
shuffle (my_list)
print (my_list)
```

Comment: That's just randomizing, not swapping/mirroring.

Comment: This is close, but not what I am looking for?, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The following code gives you the expected output.

```py
l = [1,2,3,4,5]

r = []
for i in range(len(l)):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        r.append(l[i // 2])
    else:
        r.append(l[-1 - i // 2])

print(r)  # prints [1, 5, 2, 4, 3]
```

Comment: Your solution gives also the expected result, Thanks